# Modifying x - data of a matlab figure file

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab .fig file but I don't have the data that I earlier used to create that file. I obtained the figure by plotting some X - data vs Y - data.

Now, I want to multiply all of the X - data by a constant number.

I actually have no idea how to do it.  I can multiply the X - tick labels by a constant  number. But that's not what I want. I want to multiply the actual X-data by that constant number.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to directly modify the data stored in a Matlab `.fig` file. The `.fig` file only contains the graphical objects and properties used to create the figure, not the underlying data used to generate the plot.

However, if you have the original code that was used to generate the plot, you can modify that code to multiply the `XData` by the constant number and re-create the figure.

If you do not have the original code, you may still be able to extract the `XData` from the `.fig` file using the `get()` command in Matlab. Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to extract the `XData` from a `.fig` file:

```
% Load the .fig file
fig = openfig('myfigure.fig');

% Get the handle to the line object
hLine = findobj(fig, 'type', 'line');

% Extract the X-data from the line object
xData = get(hLine, 'XData');

% Multiply the X-data by a constant number
xData = xData * constant;

% Update the X-data in the line object
set(hLine, 'XData', xData);

% Save the modified figure
saveas(fig, 'myfigure_modified.fig');

% Close the figure
close(fig);
```

This code assumes that your figure contains only one `line` object. If your figure contains multiple `line` objects, you may need to modify the code to extract and modify the `XData` for each `line` object separately.

Comment: Can you please confirm if this answer was written by you or not? Based on your other contributions on the site this answer seems like it was generated or copied from somewhere else without any attribution.